# Aggregate function in comparison of 2 rows in the same table (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Given the table definition:

```
create table mytable (
    id integer,
    mydate datetime,
    myvalue integer )
```

I want to get the following answer by a single SQL query:

```
id date_actual value_actual date_previous value_previous
```

where:

```
date_previous is the maximum of all the dates preceeding date_actual 
for each id and values correspond with the two dates 
{max(date_previous) < date_actual ?}
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks for your hints

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the common "greatest N per group" query which comes up every week on StackOverflow.

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.mydate AS date_actual, m1.myvalue AS value_actual,
  m2.mydate AS date_previous, m2.myvalue AS value_previous
FROM mytable m1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable m2 
  ON (m1.id = m2.id AND m1.mydate > m2.mydate)
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable m3 
  ON (m1.id = m3.id AND m1.mydate > m3.mydate AND m3.mydate > m2.mydate)
WHERE m3.id IS NULL;
```

In other words, `m2` is all rows with the same `id` and a lesser `mydate`, but we want only the one such that there is no row `m3` with a date between `m1` and `m2`.  Assuming the dates are unique, there will only be one row in `m2` where this is true.

Comment: @Bill: any idea how does this implementation perform compared to `... = MAX(...)`?

Comment: In my experience it performs better, but I use MySQL more than SQL Server.  I know MySQL doesn't execute group-by queries as efficiently as SQL Server does.  So you should test both queries and see how they compare in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your requirements correctly, here's something you can try.

```
select a.id, 
       a.mydate as date_actual, 
       a.value as value_actual,
       b.date as date_previous, 
       b.value as value_previous
from mytable a, mytable b
where a.id = b.id and
      a.mydate > b.mydate and
      b.mydate = (select max(mydate) from mytable c where c.id = a.id and c.mydate < a.mydate)
```

Apologies for the ugly SQL. I am sure there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: Would work if LEFT JOIN was used. As it is right now, it will not return the rows that do not have previous values.

Comment: @van, thanks for pointing that out. you are right. I'll edit the query to use left joins.